# GlassFish 3.1.1 mangles resource name then complains it can't find it

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, jndi, glassfish-3

According to [this article](http://blogs.oracle.com/JagadishPrasath/entry/application_scoped_resources_in_glassfish) and a number of other documents, JDBC resources are deployed globally (available server-wide) unless prefixed with `java:app/`. When I change `jdbc/myDataSource` to `java:app/jdbc/myDataSource` and `myConnectionPool` to `java:app/myConnectionPool`, deployment fails with this exception:

`com.sun.appserv.connectors.internal.api.ConnectorRuntimeException: Invalid resource : { ResourceInfo : (jndiName=java:app/jdbc/myDataSource__pm), (applicationName=com.example.web_example_war_1.0-SNAPSHOT) }`

It works just fine without the `java:app/` prefixes, but then the resources are deployed server-wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this section](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/glassfish/Gfv31ConnectorsJDBC#Gfv31ConnectorsJDBC-4.1.3Applicationscopedresources), I realised that I don't have to prefix resources defined in `glassfish-resources.xml` with the `java:app/` scope prefix. According to that document:

> If the resource definition is provided within an archive (ie., *glassfish-resources.xml* within an .ear or other archives), they are assumed to be scoped resources.

And then it goes on to say the resources are application scoped if the application is an EAR and the path is `META-INF/glassfish-resources.xml` or (in my case) it is a WAR and the path is `WEB-INF/glassfish-resources.xml`.

This may explain why GlassFish was mangling the name. There was most likely a name collision because I added the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Are you deploying your WAR files bundled in an a EAR file, coz as per the link you have the 'java:app/' prefix is for EAR deployment.

Comment: Yeah, just the WAR. So I tried changing to module scoped and it still could not find it. Is it not possible to deploy non-global resources with just a WAR?